# Вывод данных из бд по выбору таблицы.

Tags: php, mysql

Как мне организовать вывод содержимого таблиц по нажатию на имя таблицы. Ниже код вывода названий таблиц из бд. Все наименования таблиц содержатся в $row[0], нельзя даже обработать через POST, как из  $row[0] можно вытащить названия таблиц по 1-му, или что то в этом роде.

```
$ntable = "SHOW TABLES FROM $db";
$result = mysql_query($ntable);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "Таблица: $row[0]</br>";
}
```

Comment: что значит "нельзя даже обработать через POST"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запишите где-нибудь (в файле, в БД) соответствие НОМЕР => ИД-таблицы ну что-то типа:

- 1 => блондинки
- 2 => брюнетки
- 3 => рыженькие

В ссылке пользователю давайте ИД.

При обработке делаете что-то типа

```
$tableId = intval($_GET['table_id']);
if (isset($tableName[$tableId]))
    $sql = "select * from ".$tableName[$tableId].";";
```

Ну и "выводите содержимое" результата этого запроса.

Comment: Чесно не чего не понял, наверно потому-что я не далек в php. Может ты мог бы подробней объяснить, или сказать как мне названия таблиц вытаскивать по 1.

Comment: Как вытаскивать - я уже написал в ответе. 

Теперь о том, как добавлять:

    $ntable = "SHOW TABLES FROM $db";
    $result = mysql_query($ntable);
    $tableName = array(); 
    $c = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        $c++;
        $tableName[$c] = $row[0];
        echo '<a href=".....php?table_id='.$c.'">'.$row[0].'</a></br>';
    }

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['tables'] = $tableName;

Соответственно перед читалкой ставишь:

    session_start();
    $tableName = $_SESSION['tables'];

В сессии конечно такое писать не рекомендуется, но для учбного примера - пиде.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Ты мужик!!